# Compare hashMap values by setting tolerable margine with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I did a function that display difference between two hashmaps

For example : this is my 2 hashmaps

1st =>

```
1234 : "1.03 , 2.17 , 3"
1235 : "1 , 4 , 5"
1236 : "2 , 3 , 3"
1237 : "0.33 , 1.51 , 5"
```

2nd =>

```
1234 : "1.03 , 2.17 , 3"
1235 : "1.17 , 2 , 3.9"
1236 : "2 , 3 , 3"
1237 : "2 , 1 , 5"
```

Result =>

```
1235 : "1 , 4 , 5"
1237 : "0.33 , 1.51 , 5"
```

(the goal was to compare the first with the second and display what keys and values of the first hashmap that aren't coherent).

But now, I want to set a tolerable margin of "0.1" to each `"hpos , vpos , dpos"` of the object's value. So even if the values of the hashmaps are different by only `"0.1"` it won't display in the object `Difference` . What should I modify in my function? Btw: the value's structure of the hashmap is this :

```
positionList = iSceneGraph.merch.vpos+","+iSceneGraph.merch.hpos+","+iSceneGraph.merch.dpos.;
facingPositions[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = positionList;
```

And here is my function of comparison :

```
compareHashMap: function(iAdaptation, iActual){
                var difference = {};
                Object.keys(iActual).forEach(function(k){
                    if(iAdaptation[k] !== iActual[k]){
                        difference[k] = iActual[k];
                    }
                });
                return difference;
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Convert both values to number array and compare elementwise.

Comment: At the moment you are just comparing the strings, you need to change this comparison for each value inside your map. Then you can substract one value from another and see if the difference is bigger than 0.1

Comment: imo positionList should be an array of numeric values or an object, but not a string, otherwise you'll have to decode it again.

Comment: Let suppose I have an array instead of a string, what should I change in my function? @matus

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment let's suppose inside your function you have 2 arrays instead of strings, one for actual numbers one for adaptation. Then in your for each function you can add:

```
compareHashMap: function(iAdaptation, iActual){    
  var difference = {};
  Object.keys(iActual).forEach(function(k){ 

    for(key in iActual[k]){
      if(Math.abs(iActual[k][key] - iAdaptation[k][key]) > 0.1){ //Math.abs will return absolute value of the number (positive value in case difference is minus)
        difference[k] = iActual[k];
      } 
    }
  });
  return difference;
}
```

This is just an example, yI didn't try to run this code.

Comment: it's okey , I understood the principle.. Thanks @Matus